# android adaptor row hiding

Tags: android, adapter

In arrayAdptor we use following code:

```
 final LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    row = (LinearLayoutCustom) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    final TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    label.setText(position + "" + items[position]); 
    return row;
```

Now suppose  some value are null (for example at position 2 ,  items[2] = null ) so  i dont want to show it in row. i want to hide it. if i use

```
               row.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

it leaves a blank space at this row which i dont want. so what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have the adapter return the total number of non-null items with `getCount` and then keep a mapping of position to your internal data structure.

For example.
You have a list

```
1 - John
2 - null
3 - Bill
4 - Susan
5 - null
```

When getCount is called it returns 3.

Then when `getView` is called on position 1 you return the item at `list[1]`.
`getView` on position 2 returns `list[3]` (as it's the 2nd non-null), 
and so forth.

This is the only way I've found to do this.

Comment: if getView on position 2 return list[3] then why am i  getting null row. i think it is returning null so i am getting blank row

Comment: No the trick is you have to have the adapter ignore null rows when calculating the number of rows.  If you return a null row you will get a blank space.  So you have to have the adapter only tell the listview about rows that aren't null.

Comment: hmm that may be a solution but it seems complex. any other solution? if this is the only way to do, can you give me hint that how can i do mapping of this type?

Comment: No idea if their is another way, this is the way I've been doing it.  I've had luck keeping an extra array to keep track of mapping. If their is another way I would love to know how.

Comment: It's not complex to ignore null positions. In your adapter's getView() method just add while(array[position] == null){ position++}. This will skip the null values.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK you can't return a null view from `getView`, but you could just make the view invisible and height 1. Although manipulating using the `getCount` is probably the preferred way.

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
view.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though. What about changing that `view.getLayoutParams().height` dynamically? Would the listView adapt correctly? I mean, in my case i want to hide the row but show it again after some event/time.

Comment: perfect, that works fine.
the height has to be 1 (0 won't work).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a View that has no height for the "hidden" items so that you don't have to do all the model housekeeping and mapping. For example, suppose you had a "filter" EditText field that when data is entered it only keeps matching items:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater   inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.id.myListLayout, null, false);

    ...

    // if we didn't match filter be GONE and leave
    if (filterText.length() > 0 && myModelValueAtPosition.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) < 0){
        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myListLayoutWithZeroHeight, null, false);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this doesn't really do anything useful; I'd hoped it would work by itself, but turns out the zero height layout is the key
        return view;
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to write the logic in your [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29),[getItemId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId%28int%29) and [getItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29),
It will create the no of rows what the getCount return

```
//How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
    public int getCount() {
            return //Should return the count of rows you need to display (here the count excluding null values)
        }
```

And

```
//This need to return data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return //Return the object need to display at position, need the logic to skip null value  
    }
```

Edit:So in your getview

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
         ---- 
        getItem(position);//Object corresponding to position ,In your case it will not be null since you need to write the logic to skip null object at getItem
        ----
}
```

Comment: i can find non null item by this (getItem(position) != null) but how this can be integrated with getView method. getView will always return some view.and it is called autometically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I implemented, here is a code example for everyone that is looking it:

```
class Shipment_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Shipment>{
     ....
     ArrayList<Integer> emptyPositions = new ArrayList<>();

     public Shipment_Adapter(Context context, int shipment_row, Shipment[] myShipments){
        super(context, R.layout.shipment_row,myShipments);

        //populate emptyPositions list
        for(int i = 0; i< myShipments.length; i++){
            if(myShipments[i]==null){
                emptyPositions.add(i);
            }
        }

        this.mShipment = myShipments;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    //corrects size of List
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (mShipment.length - emptyPositions.size());
    }

    //recursive function that checks if position is not empty until it isn't
    public int isEmpty(int positiontocheck){
         int newposition;
         if(emptyPositions.contains(positiontocheck)){
             //true? check that next one is free
            return isEmpty(positiontocheck+1);
         }else{
            newposition = positiontocheck;
         }

         return newposition;
     }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //now just need to use isEmpty to get the next not empty position in 
    //case our real position is empty

    position= isEmpty(position);

    Shipment shipment = mShipment[position];

    ...//and so on

 }
```

hope this helps!