# Hiding List View Row without having spacing in it

Tags: android, listview, row, listviewitem

how to remove a space even I am succeed in hiding a row, but it shows a white space in there. It will hide a row when Status will be equal to 'Awarded' as given below. help me thanks in advance.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity context;
    String ref[];
    String policy[];
    String natureofloss[];
    String make[];
    String registration[];
    String modelname[];
    String year[];
    String amount[];
    String status[];
    String quot_id[];

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] ref, String[] policy,
            String[] natureofloss, String[] make, String[] registration,
            String[] modelname, String[] year, String[] amount,
            String[] status, String[] qout_id) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.ref = ref;
        this.policy = policy;
        this.natureofloss = natureofloss;
        this.make = make;
        this.registration = registration;
        this.modelname = modelname;
        this.year = year;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.status = status;
        this.quot_id = qout_id;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ref.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView ref;
        TextView policy;
        TextView natureofloss;
        TextView make;
        TextView registration;
        TextView modelname;
        TextView year;
        TextView amount;
        TextView status;
        TextView quot_id;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ref = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_refpolicyno);
            holder.policy = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_policyno);
            holder.natureofloss = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_natureofloss);
            holder.make = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_make);
            holder.registration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_registration);
            holder.modelname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_modelname);
            holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_year);
            holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            holder.quot_id = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_quotid_clientqoutlist);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (!status[position].equals("Awarded")) {
            holder.ref.setText(ref[position]);
            holder.policy.setText("/" + policy[position]);
            holder.natureofloss.setText(natureofloss[position]);
            holder.make.setText(make[position]);
            holder.registration.setText(registration[position]);
            holder.modelname.setText(modelname[position]);
            holder.year.setText(year[position]);
            holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
            holder.status.setText(status[position]);
            holder.quot_id.setText(quot_id[position]);
        } else {
            convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Screen Shot of rows

[image]

Comment: why your are making `convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` remove that element from array is don't need you further

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907891/android-adaptor-row-hiding

Answer (score 1):

You need to create adapter that will return the total number of not null items with getCount() and then keep a getting the positions of your data.

**Ex.** You are having a list as position 1 - A , 2 - B, 3 - null, 4 - D, 5 - null

When getCount is called it returns 3.

at that time getView is called on position 1 you return the item at list[1]. getView on position 3 returns list[4] (as 4th position is non-null), and so on.

Comment: Hope this may help you!